# Tracking device useage on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I've been using this app called Moment that tracks how much time I spend on my device every day. I think it's very cool, and at the same time am very curious how it works. I don't have tons of mobile development experience, as I've mainly built web apps, but I'm curious how this kind of functionality could be achieved.

I did a few quick Google searches and found that iOS does have some support for background task execution. The functionality lies in four categories:

1. Play audio
2. Receive location updates
3. Perform finite-length tasks
4. Background fetch

It looks like I can't do anything tricky using audio callbacks, as Apple will reject the app, but I'm wondering if I can do something with (3).

Answer (score 0):

They do it using **Custom Profiles**.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Kashif - any chance you could elaborate a little more, to point me in the right direction? I'm not familiar with this at all.